# When I run this code the following errors appear:

Tags: javascript, webgl, p5.js

When I try to run the code below the following 2 errors pop up:

> WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: vertexAttribPointer: index out of range
>
> WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range

What is the problem with the code and what should I do to fix it?

```
let cols, rows;
let h = 600;
let w = 600;
let scl = 20;   
let terrain = [];

function setup() {

    createCanvas(600,600,WEBGL);
    background(0);
    cols = w / scl;
    rows = h / scl;
    for (i = 0; i <= rows*cols-1; i++){

        terrain[i] = random(-10,10);
    }
}

function draw() {

  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotateX(PI/3);
  translate(-w/2, -h/2);

  for( let y = 0; y < rows; y++){

        beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
        for( let x = 0; x < cols; x++){

            vertex(x*scl,y*scl,terrain[y+x*rows]);
            vertex(x*scl,(y+1)*scl,terrain[y+1+x*rows]);
        }
        endShape();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, right. Didn't notice that. I have changed that, but it still gives the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get into the habit of googling your errors. Googling `WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: enableVertexAttribArray: index out of range` returns a ton of results, including this one: [beginShape should not require call to fill() in order to render](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1678)

Basically, this is telling you that you don't have a fill color, so you won't be able to see the stuff you're drawing. Change the `noFill()` line to something like `fill(255, 0, 0)` to see the stuff you're drawing.

Btw, in the future please try to narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll often figure out the problem yourself in the process of coming up with a small example, like in this case narrowing the problem down to the `noFill()` call. Good luck.

Comment: @gman Did you try running the code? It shows up as a yellow warning, not a red error. Did you try reading the link in my answer? It agrees that it's a warning, not an error. In any case, the solution is to set a fill color. I've tested that and it works. Please consider reversing your downvote.

Comment: INVALID_VALUE is an error. It is returned by glGetError. It doesn't matter what color the message is. It's an error as defined by the WebGL spec

Comment: @gman Fine, I've edited out the bit about it being a warning. But please note that other resources say it's a warning instead of an error, not just me.

Comment: It does fix the warnings, but fills the entire terrain I am generating with the color I set the fill() to and overwrites any white lines between vertices.

Comment: @MihaiBurța Right, that's what I would expect it to do. If you have a follow-up question, please post an updated [mcve] (note that this should **not** be your whole program, just a small example) in a new question post. Good luck.

Comment: p5.js has a bug, it should be fixed. Any WebGL program that generates WebGL errors (errors that would be reported by gl.getError()` is buggy. Ignoring the errors just because the program still runs only serves to hide more errors later down the line (since people get used to ignoring the messages) and/or make it hard to debug other errors (since if you actually call `gl.getError` to see if you're getting an error somewhere else will end up returning a false positive since it will be indicating the error you ignored instead of the error you were checking for).

Comment: @gman I'm not sure who that comment was directed towards. I'm not responsible for the P5.js WebGL code. If you want to file an issue, you can use the link in my answer to reach the GitHub repo for P5.js.

Comment: It's directed at your comment that people claim it's a warning. It's not a warning, it's an error. The code incorrectly called WebGL.

Comment: @gman Again, feel free to file an issue against P5.js if it's bothering you. I don't really have anything to do with it. :p

Comment: I didn't claim you had anything to do with p5. I'm only responding to your claim that it's only a warning.

Comment: @gman I've already deleted that claim. But that claim didn't originate from me. I was repeating what the original developer of P5.js said. But again, I've since deleted it because I don't think it really matters anyway. OP can solve their problem by simple setting the fill color, which presumably they've already done since they accepted this answer.